# Bash - how to format a time-stamp variable to human readable format

Tags: bash, datetime-format

At the beginning of my script I set a variable *DATE*, which I need to use in different parts of the script and in different formats.

My issue is to use the same variable but format it in different ways:

```
#!/bin/bash
DATE=$(date +%s)
echo "date in timestamp format: $DATE"
echo "..."
# some other actions that need time...
echo "date start at: $(date $(DATE +%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M))"
```

this runs but outputs an error (*DATE: command not found*):

```
date in timestamp format: 1490884719
...
<script>.sh: line 6: DATE: command not found
date start at: Thu Mar 30 16:38:40 CEST 2017
```

how do I get rid of the error?

Comment: You are running `DATE` in a subshell. Maybe you meant to do `echo "date start at: $(date -d"$DATE" '+%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M')"`

Comment: That does not seem to work either:  date: invalid date `1490885663'

Comment: Try `-d"@$DATE"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the `$(...)` is trying to execute the `DATE` command, without success. Coincidentally, `date` is running anyway, with no arguments, returning the current time (looking similar to the original).

Try replacing the whole line with something like:

`echo "date start at: $(date --date=@${DATE} '+%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M')"`

for GNU date (Linux and friends), and:

`echo "date start at: $(date -j -f '%s' ${DATE} '+%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M')"`

for BSD date (macOS and other BSDs).